# Ecommerce Loyalty Points/Rewards program

Tags: e-commerce, kentico, discount, reward-system

I'm looking to build a Loyalty Points/Reward system on the back of the Credit payment provider, however I would like it to be able to:

- Allow visitor do redeem balance or not during the basket/checkout stage
- Allow visitor to pay the outstanding order amount with any of the other payment providers.

I've considered a lot of possible approaches but am wondering whether someone else has achieved this successfully?

I'd assume I'd have to tap some method on the shopppingcartinfoprovider before processing the payment with the chosen payment provider (other than credit/full amount) but how best to apply the discount to the order? 
Create an actual discount on the fly? Use a faux product with a variable unit price? Are there any tax considerations I must have? Is there any other recommended best method?

Thanks,

Comment: Doesn't the [customer credit](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Customers+credit) feature already allow you to do those things?

Comment: Not as you'd expect a loyalty point/reward program to work because "
Your customers can pay for the purchased products using one payment method only" so I can't redeem my credit to partial pay an order...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a discount to the order in the height of the credit amount associated with the customer account. You can store the credit balance in the OrderCustomData field and subtract it after the order has been paid. You can tap into the CalculateOrderDiscountInternal method in the CustomShoppingCartInfoProvider.cs or the EvaluateShoppingCart method (http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/9_0/api/html/M_CMS_Ecommerce_ShoppingCartInfoProvider_EvaluateShoppingCart.htm). More information on e-commerce customization best practices can be found here: http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/e-commerce-customization-best-practices You can also check the code samples in c:\Program Files (x86)\Kentico\9.0\CodeSamples\App_Code Samples\E-commerce samples\

Comment: Could you provide an example on how to apply a discount if i override the CalculateOrderDiscountInternal method? Please not that i dont want to lose any of the existing discount functionalities. Thanks.

Comment: Please check the examples I referenced under c:\Program Files (x86)\Kentico\9.0\CodeSamples\App_Code Samples\E-commerce samples\... you will find one there.